Weird problem with ParallelTable: assigning variables does not work
Consider the following three codes:
test1 = ParallelTable[
    Module[{solutionsThermodynamics, 
      tIniEM}, {solutionsThermodynamics, tIniEM} = 
      DynamicsTimeScaleFactorNumberDens[1.2, \[Tau], 10^-12., 0.33, 
       tmaxsol]], {\[Tau], 0.1, 1, 0.3}] /. {t -> 0.3, T -> 10^-3};
test2 = Table[
    Module[{solutionsThermodynamics, 
      tIniEM}, {solutionsThermodynamics, 
       tIniEM} = {solutionsThermodynamics, tIniEM} = 
       DynamicsTimeScaleFactorNumberDens[1.2, \[Tau], 10^-12., 0.33, 
        tmaxsol]], {\[Tau], 0.1, 1, 0.3}] /. {t -> 0.3, T -> 10^-3};
test3 = ParallelTable[
    DynamicsTimeScaleFactorNumberDens[1.2, \[Tau], 10^-12., 0.33, 
     tmaxsol], {\[Tau], 0.1, 1, 0.3}] /. {t -> 0.3, T -> 10^-3};
test1 == test2 == test3

Here, DynamicsTimeScaleFactorNumberDens[1.2, \[Tau], 10^-12., 0.33,  tmaxsol] is some particular code whose nature is not really relevant to this question. The outputs of test2, test3 are the same:
{{{2.442*10^-17, 0.74380517055166, 0.001570359754011111, 
   12.758317770920902, 
       20.097387595842466, 1.65835*10^-9, 1.64299*10^-9, 1.16553*10^6, 
       0.6731297573526371, 1.5687320347534661, 0.0009962162455145421, 
   1.5685135636950567, 
       0.000995981253726738, 1.5684683529395247, 
   0.0009959159075787984}, 0.0018442627424352358}, 
   {{2.28507*10^-16, 0.7438030338125651, 0.0015703567772148716, 
   12.75833154950717, 
       20.09739992882883, 1.65837*10^-9, 1.643*10^-9, 1.16552*10^6, 
       0.6731331125568687, 1.5687292208642372, 0.0009962179717112878, 
   1.5685106370026711, 
       0.0009959829588395627, 1.5684654253902606, 
   0.0009959176311483946}, 0.0018442627424352358}}

However, test1 returns errors Lists {solutionsThermodynamics$2092,tIniEM$2092} and DynamicsTimeScaleFactorNumberDens[1.2,0.1,1.*10^-12,0.33,tmaxsol] are not the same shape. It is probably related to assigning variables inside ParallelTable.
The version without Module, test1 = ParallelTable[{solutionsThermodynamics, tIniEM} =  DynamicsTimeScaleFactorNumberDens[1.2, \[Tau], 10^-12., 0.33,  tmaxsol], {\[Tau], 0.1, 1, 0.3}] /. {t -> 0.3, T -> 10^-3};, also does not work.
Could you please tell me what a generic reason for this is, and how to fix it?

We cannot reproduce your problem without your definition of the DynamicsTimeScaleFactorNumberDens function. If that is too complicated to share, then please reduce your problem to a smaller one with a fictitious function. I am also confused by the double assignment in test2, i.e. the {solutionsThermodynamics, tIniEM} = {solutionsThermodynamics, tIniEM} = DynamicsTimeScaleFactorNumberDens[...]: what does that accomplish?

If the message has DynamicsTimeScaleFactorNumberDens[..] in it, it means that DynamicsTimeScaleFactorNumberDens[..] did not evaluate to something different than what is shown.. Ditto for tmaxsol (well, perhaps depending on DynamicsTimeScaleFactorNumberDens[]), but maybe tmaxsol is supposed to be uninitialized as that's how it appears in the code. I suppose  /. {t -> 0.3, T -> 10^-3} is irrelevant, since there is no dependence in the code on t or T.  Generic reasons: (1) You did something wrong. (2) Hidden dependencies are a source of bugs.

Please do not use the bugs tag until community confirmation/reproduction shows a bug.
